# How to query data from Postgresql Elephant DB in bluemix?

Tags: postgresql, ibm-cloud

One of my app requirements is to query data from elephant DB in bluemix.
How will i achieve the function?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: can you please accept an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Elephant SQL is Postgres.  You can use any Postgres driver that you want.

Answer (score -1):

If your application is a Java Web application, Liberty buildpack supports auto-configuration of a DataSource for connecting to the Elephant SQL service when such a service is bound to your application, see https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/starters/liberty/index.html#automaticconfigurationofboundservices. This makes it easier for your app to access the Elephant service, by simply using resource injection to get a DataSource object.